# d3js multiple networks issue

Tags: d3.js, d3-force-directed

The scenario:

I have d3 rendering multiple networks.

It consists of single nodes, multiple connected node networks.

I am trying to attach d3-force (simulation) so that the nodes dont overlap when dragged and the entire network maintains relative positioning.

Am using the manybody force.

The problem:

1. When the simulation loads (simulation.restart()), the entire network keeps spreading apart. All nodes/networks keep moving away indefinitely.
2. Even when nodes from one network are dragged, all other networks move.

Would greatly appreciate if anyone can point me to the right solution.

Heres a small fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/pdubey84/or0tn49k/2/

[image: Network]

```
var nodes = [
  { id: "mammal", group: 0, label: "Mammals", level: 1 },
  { id: "dog"   , group: 0, label: "Dogs"   , level: 2 },
  { id: "cat"   , group: 0, label: "Cats"   , level: 2 },
  { id: "fox"   , group: 0, label: "Foxes"  , level: 2 },
  { id: "elk"   , group: 0, label: "Elk"    , level: 2 },
  { id: "insect", group: 1, label: "Insects", level: 1 },
  { id: "ant"   , group: 1, label: "Ants"   , level: 2 },
  { id: "bee"   , group: 1, label: "Bees"   , level: 2 },
  { id: "fish"  , group: 2, label: "Fish"   , level: 1 },
  { id: "carp"  , group: 2, label: "Carp"   , level: 2 },
  { id: "pike"  , group: 2, label: "Pikes"  , level: 2 },
  { id: "pike"  , group: 3, label: "Pikes"  , level: 1 },
  { id: "pike"  , group: 4, label: "Pikes"  , level: 1 },
  { id: "pike"  , group: 4, label: "Pikes"  , level: 1 },
  { id: "foo"  , group: 4, label: "foo"  , level: 1 },
    { id: "bar"  , group: 4, label: "bar"  , level: 1 }
]

var links = [
    { target: "mammal", source: "dog" , strength: 0.7 },
    { target: "mammal", source: "cat" , strength: 0.7 },
  { target: "mammal", source: "fox" , strength: 0.7 },
  { target: "mammal", source: "elk" , strength: 0.7 },
  { target: "insect", source: "ant" , strength: 0.7 },
  { target: "insect", source: "bee" , strength: 0.7 },
  { target: "fish"  , source: "carp", strength: 0.7 },
  { target: "fish"  , source: "pike", strength: 0.7 },
  { target: "cat"   , source: "elk" , strength: 0.1 },
  { target: "carp"  , source: "ant" , strength: 0.1 },
  { target: "elk"   , source: "bee" , strength: 0.1 },
  { target: "dog"   , source: "cat" , strength: 0.1 },
  { target: "fox"   , source: "ant" , strength: 0.1 },
    { target: "pike"  , source: "cat" , strength: 0.1 },
    { target: "foo"  , source: "bar" , strength: 0.1 }
]



function getNodeColor(node, neighbors) {
  return 'red'
}


function getLinkColor(node, link) {
  return '000'
}

var width = window.innerWidth
var height = window.innerHeight

var svg = d3.select('svg')
svg.attr('width', width).attr('height', height)

// simulation setup with all forces
var linkForce = d3
  .forceLink()
  .id(function (link) { return link.id })
  .strength(function (link) { return link.strength })

var simulation = d3
  .forceSimulation()
  .force('link', linkForce)
  .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody().strength(-500).distanceMax(50))
  .force('center', d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))


var dragDrop = d3.drag().on('start', function (node) {
  node.fx = node.x
  node.fy = node.y
}).on('drag', function (node) {
  simulation.alphaTarget(0.7).restart()
  node.fx = d3.event.x
  node.fy = d3.event.y
}).on('end', function (node) {
  if (!d3.event.active) {
    simulation.alphaTarget(0)
  }
  node.fx = null
  node.fy = null
})

var linkElements = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "links")
  .selectAll("line")
  .data(links)
  .enter().append("line")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1)
      .attr("stroke", "rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.2)")

var nodeElements = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "nodes")
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(nodes)
  .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", 10)
    .attr("fill", getNodeColor)
    .call(dragDrop)


simulation.nodes(nodes).on('tick', () => {
  nodeElements
    .attr('cx', function (node) { return node.x })
    .attr('cy', function (node) { return node.y })
  linkElements
    .attr('x1', function (link) { return link.source.x })
    .attr('y1', function (link) { return link.source.y })
    .attr('x2', function (link) { return link.target.x })
    .attr('y2', function (link) { return link.target.y })
})

simulation.force("link").links(links)
```

Answer (score 0):

Both behaviours are expected. This is what you can do for those issues:

1. Network spreading apart: I suppose you're talking about the dragging function, since when loaded the simulation runs only 300 ticks. If that is the case, use `simulation.alpha` instead of `simulation.alphaTarget`. `simulation.alpha` is the correct way to control the entropy:

   ```
   simulation.alpha(0.7).restart();
   ```
2. When you drag one network, all networks move: that happens because you are using `d3.forceCenter()`. According to the [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-force#centering):

   > The centering force translates nodes uniformly so that the mean position of **all nodes** (the center of mass if all nodes have equal weight) is at the given position. (emphasis mine)

What you can do is cancelling this force when you drag for the first time:

```
simulation.force("center", null)
```

Here is your fiddle with those two changes: https://jsfiddle.net/yjkgdgad/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response @Gerardo... I tried your solution, but the problem is still the same.... Every time I try to drag a component, every other connected component starts moving.... Its kind of a problem when I have lot of large networks... I was wondering if somehow I could identify each component and then aply forces only to those components, that ways they wouldnt move anything else. Thoughts?

Comment: Well, that's a *third* problem, that's not in your question: that happens because you are re-heating the simulation.

Comment: Hi @gerardo ... Sorry to bug u with it, but I tried a bunch of things but still the third problem I mentioned persists. Do you happen to know a way by which I can have multiple components have different forces so that they dont interfere with each other?

Comment: The best idea is posting another question: if you ask this here, in the comments, I'm the only one reading, but if you ask a new question, everybody is gonna read it!